# collection_select truncate

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, truncate

How can i truncate the value in a collection_select

```
<%= collection_select(:standard, :parent_id, Standard.all, :id, :value, {:include_blank => 'No Parent'} ) %>
```

I would like to have the value shortened, but am getting errors with this:

```
<%= collection_select(:standard, :parent_id, Standard.all, :id, truncate(:value, :length => 40), {:include_blank => 'No Parent'} ) %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1:**

Add a custom method to your Model, something like `truncated_value`, and use that instead:

```
class Standard < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper

  def truncated_value
    truncate(value, :length => 40)
  end

  ...
  ...
  ...
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= collection_select(:standard, 
                      :parent_id, 
                      Standard.all, 
                      :id, 
                      :truncated_value, 
                      {:include_blank => 'No Parent'}) %>
```

**Option 2:**

Just use a the `select` tag helper instead:

```
<%= select(:standard, 
           :parent_id, 
           Standard.all.collect{ |s| [truncate(s.value, :length => 40), s.id] },
           {:include_blank => 'No Parent'}) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by passing `text_method` as `proc` as the following:

```
<%= collection_select(:standard, 
                  :parent_id, 
                  Standard.all, 
                  :id, 
                  proc {|st| st.value.truncate(40)}, 
                  {:include_blank => 'No Parent'}) %>
```

For more info I notice that [collection_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) receive the value as `text_method`, so I send block of code using [proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Proc.html).